# How to get all JDT AST Statement's at a given line number?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

How can I get the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Statement` at a given line number?

Assume I have this class:

```
 1 package foo;
 2 public class Operations {
 3  public static int calc(int a, int b) {
 4      if (a >= b)
 5          return a - b;
 6      if (a<b || b==2)
 7          return -1;
 8      return 0;
 9  }
10 }
```

This is what i expect:

- line 3 -> `BlockStatement`
- line 4 -> `IfStatement`
- line 5 -> `ReturnStatement`

This code works but it is a bit bulky because every body and statement must be visited in the worsed case. Is there a better/simpler way to do it?

```
List<Statement> getStatementsAtLine(final CompilationUnit cu, final int lineNumber) {
        final List<Statement> result = new ArrayList<Statement>();
        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
            @Override
            public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
                Block body = node.getBody();

                for (Statement s : (List<Statement>) body.statements()) {
                    int l=cu.getLineNumber(s.getStartPosition());
                    if (l==lineNumber){
                        result.add(s);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to convert the line number into a (character-) position using

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.getPosition(int, int)
```

With that offset you can use the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.NodeFinder` to retrieve the `ASTNode` at that position, s.t. like:

```
NodeFinder finder= new NodeFinder(cu, offset, 0);
ASTNode node= finder.getCoveringNode();
while (node != null && !(node instanceof Statement)) {
    node= node.getParent();
}
return node;
```

EDIT:
This approach, however, has a problem with white space, because leading or trailing white space characters are not covered by the statement being sought.

I see two possible strategies to avoid this problem:

1. Increment the `offset` until you are sure it is "within" the significant text of the line, or
2. Apply the trick from a comment below: extend the region up-to the end-of-file and ask for the largest `ASTNode` completely covered by this region (using `getCoveredNode()` instead of `getCoveringNode()`).

Strategy (1) requires to retrieve the text of the line in question via the IDocument, which may not be readily available.
Strategy (2) may have the effect that a statement spanning several lines may be selected, not sure if this is against any requirement. If more precision is needed, calculate the length argument for `getPosition()` as the difference between the current line start and the next line start.

Comment: I tried your solution, it doesn't return the statement at the given line but the whole Block that consists of all lines in the current scope. It works paricular if i use `cu.getPosition(lineNumber+1, 0)` for IfStatement but it doesn't for ReturnStatements. In other words: If i calc the offset of a return statement I get a Block and not as expected a ReturnStatement.

Comment: Okay i found two problems in your example: The 3rd argument of `new NodeFinder` must not be 0 but `cu.getLength()`. And instead of `finder.getCoveringNode()` the method `finder.getGoveredNode()` must be called. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Any one know how to get all ASTNodes within a line range?

Comment: @K.Symbol the internal class `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.dom.ASTNodes` has a method `getChildren()`, which you could easily copy incl. its `ChildrenCollector` (copy so you don't depend on internal classes). Apply this to the covered node of the code region and you should get approximately what you are asking for. If you need to get only a subset of sibling nodes, I suggest you copy and adjust `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.NodeFinder`.